# how to fix javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

```
DELIMITER $$ 
DROP view 
IF EXISTS `poliklinik`.`view_daftar_pasien`$$ 
  CREATE algorithm=undefined definer=`root`@`localhost` SQL security definer view `view_daftar_pasien`
  AS 
    ( 
           SELECT `pendaftaran`.`no_antri`  AS `no_antri`, 
                  `pendaftaran`.`id_daftar` AS `id_daftar`, 
                  `pasien`.`nama_pasien`    AS `nama_pasien`, 
                  `pendaftaran`.`id_dokter` AS `id_dokter`, 
                  ( 
                         SELECT IF(isnull( 
                                ( 
                                       SELECT `rekam_medis`.`id_daftar` AS `id_daftar` 
                                       FROM   `rekam_medis` 
                                       WHERE  ( 
                                                     `rekam_medis`.`id_daftar` = `pendaftaran`.`id_daftar`))),_utf8'Belum Diperiksa',IF(isnull(
                                ( 
                                       SELECT `rekam_medis`.`id_daftar` AS `id_daftar` 
                                       FROM   `rekam_medis` 
                                       WHERE  (( 
                                                            `rekam_medis`.`id_daftar` = `pendaftaran`.`id_daftar`)
                                              AND    ( 
                                                            `rekam_medis`.`rekomendasi_lab` = _latin1'Ya')))),_utf8'Sudah Diperiksa',_utf8'Cek Laboratorium')) AS `if((select id_daftar from rekam_medis where id_daftar = pendaftaran.``id_daftar``) is null,'belum diperiksa',if((select id_daftar from rekam_medis where id_daftar = pendaftaran.``id_daftar`` and rekomendasi_lab = 'ya') is null,'sudah diperiksa','cek laboratori`) AS `keterangan`, 
                  `pendaftaran`.`tgl` AS `tgl` 
           FROM   (`pendaftaran` 
           JOIN   `pasien` 
           ON    (( 
                                `pendaftaran`.`id_pasien` = `pasien`.`id_pasien`))))$$ 
    delimiter ;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Fix what? all I see is a poorly formatted SQL query. I'm not even going to try and read it this way. Please fix your formatting, follow some kind of coding style for indentation and formulate your actual question. Don't put the question in the title and just expect us to understand what you mean.

Comment: From the exception, it's telling you that one of the subquery is returning more than 1 result which it isn't suppose to, you have to try looking at which subquery returns more than 1 result